# How can I authenticate a user based on correct/incorrect credentials, but ignore their "is_active" state if I want to handle it separately?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

Currently with django's default **auth.authenticate** method, it will return `None` if the credentials are correct, but `user.is_active` is false.

This means that users who have correctly entered their credentials but haven't verified their account/email will receive the same error message as users who have incorrectly entered their credentials.
I am looking to provide users with an error message for an edge case when they've entered the correct credentials, but haven't activated their account via email verification and thus `user.is_active=False`.

My question is how do I implement this safely and efficiently?

views.py:

```
...
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
    
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        if username and password:
            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
                else:
                    uidb64 = Base64.get_uidb64(user)
                    message = format_html("Please check your email for a verification link, or <a href='{}'>click here to request a new one.</a>", reverse('accounts:verify', kwargs={'uidb64':uidb64}))
                    messages.error(request, message)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid account credentials. Please try again.')
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
```

Comment: Write a custom auth backend. Copy django auth backend to custom auth backend and change it accordingly.